# Connection problems MS SQL 2008 in EAP 6.4

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jboss

I am new to JBoss EAP and using 6.4 version . Earlier I have been using Tomcat 7.39. I like to shift from tomcat to JBOSS EAP 6.4. From some posts in stack overflow and JBOSS EAP , I some how configure MS SQL 2008 in JBOSS EAP but it is not working .

Standalone.xml File

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
      <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TMS" pool-name="TMS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TMS;integratedSecurity=false;</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>1234</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Earlier as I do not have any **pool-name** , I have deleted this attribute from **datasource** tag. Now I have just kept the pool name as database name though I do not have any pool name yet. Should I have to create pool-name and how could I do that ?

I Created (***com\microsoft\sqlserver\main***) this folder structure in ***EAP_HOME\modules*** and Then there I kept **sqljdbc4.jar** and **module.xml**. I am using windows 7, 32 bit machine. Below is the code snippet of module.xml:-

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
 <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
 </resources>
 <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
 </dependencies>
```

And I am getting this error **ERROR com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from [Module "deployment.TSM_UI.war:main" from Service Module Loader]**
I am thinking that it might be due to my pool name.Any suggestion. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The Error-Message doesn't look complete. I guess it is "ERROR ClassNotFoundEcxeption: Could not load class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from [Module "deployment.TSM_UI.war:main" from Service Module Loader]" ?
Then you try to load the driver directly from within your deployment, but you should use a JNDI-lookup to get the connection from the datasource you created.
Search your deployment (TSM_UI.war) whether you have any references to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver within your deployment and remove it.

Comment: Also I donnt have any reference  to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.

Comment: .Also When I run same code as java applicaqtion it is working fine. I think there might be problems  for jboss

Comment: When you run the same code as java application you need to load the driver yourself. So you have to have some reference to the driver in your code.

Comment: In JBoss you don't have the driver class visible from your deployment. You can lookup the configured datasource and the datasource sees the driver, but your application doesn't see the driver, that is why you get the error. (Please provide the full error-message)

Comment: 21:48:27,717 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TSM_UI].[LoginController]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginController threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.TSM.DBConnection.BO.doAuthenticate(BO.java:23) [classes:]
 at com.TSM.Filter.ValidUserSessionFilter.doFilter(ValidUserSessionFilter.java:77) [classes:]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.TSM.DBConnection.BO.doAuthenticate(BO.java:23)
 com.TSM.Filter.ValidUserSessionFilter.doFilter(ValidUserSessionFilter.java:77)12:19:59,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ERROR com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from [Module "deployment.TSM_UI.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: So its not a ClassNotFoundException as I thought, but a NullPointerException in your code (BO.java:23).

Comment: Yes It is NPE as db connection is returning null as it got Class Not found Exception? I am using JDK1.8. What would be the possible errors? I am using sqljdbc4.jar. please see my question and tell me If I am wrong in standalone or module.xml or in other artifacts.Also I am using Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: The configuration looks ok. Its probably a problem in how you lookup the connection. But its difficult to guess, when you don't show any of your application-code, persistence.xml or whatever method you use.